# Windows Universal Apps: Reusable xaml as template

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have 4 pivot items in my page. Each item contains the same listView/Long list selector just with different subset of data loaded

how can i define the data template for this listView once and then just reference it in the pivot pages?

i'm kinda new to windows xaml apps. i googled but couldn't find any satisfying solution

Answer (score 0):

Define your Template in a xaml file like ContactImageTemplate.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContactImageTemplate">
        <Border Padding="5" CornerRadius="15">
            <Grid MaxHeight="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
               ...
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then reference the template file your App.xaml this way

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary Source="Views/Controls/ContactImageTemplate.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

In your view reference the template this way

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactsListView"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactImageTemplate}"      
          ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" /ListView>
```